# Avoid passing large data between function calls

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I'm absolutely new to `C`, so please bear with me. I'm writing a parser to open number of text files -- roughly 300 Kb each, to read them character-by-character and extract the needed information. The processing has three different stages and it requires about ten different functions to work on each chunk of string, one after each other.

Since the files are not tiny and there might be a lot of them, I'm trying to write a code that is efficient and also meets the industry standards.

To me it seems that these are my options:

**A) Nested Function Calls:** Let say my `main` function calls `read_file`, then `read_file` calls `get_lines`, then `get_lines` call `get_name` and so on.

The advantage of this solution is that if I have one `while` loop in my `read_file` function, then directly and inside the loop I can call `get_name` function; However if I return the data from `get_lines` function to `main`, then I have to loop through it again and pass the data to `get_name` for example.

The problem though here is that it is not very a organised way of doing things. In this case my main function would only call the `read_file` function and then in the end write the out put data into a file.

I guess the `main` function should control the overall execution of the program, meaning it should call a function to do some business logic, then retrieve the data back and pass it over to the next function and so on. Am I right here or it's a wrong assumption?

**B) Global Variables:** This way I will define couple of *Global Variables* and then I will just work on them without a need for passing them around from this function to another function.

Since it doesn't need returning data in the end of functions' life, it must be more efficient; However I'm not a big fan of *Global Variables* in general, even in a statically typed and sync environment. I might be unnecessarily worried about it though.

**C) Passing Pointers Around:** To me it seems the way that I should go for it; However since these data is local to the function scope, I'm gonna have *Wild Pointers* hanging around. The `static` keyword solves the invalid pointers' issue; However it seems more experienced people are trying to avoid using it for some reason. So I'm not quite sure if that's a good practice or not.

**Question:** I don't have any real-world experience in `C`, therefore I can't see what are the real pros and cons of above solutions. For example, does using `static` keyword and passing a pointer around gives me any advantage over using global variables?

In other words, a short list of pros and cons of each method in this specific case will definitely help me choose one out of three.

Comment: I'd love to know what is wrong with the question. I can try my best to address the issue then.

Comment: Too broad/opinion based. Show an actual example and be more specific.

Comment: I'm not the biggest C expert on the block, but I don't see what's unattractive about global variables; as you note, they eliminate passing, at the cost of the data they hold residing on the heap instead of the stack (a little slower for each access, as I understand it).  Used carefully, globals can increase readability of the code, and simplify debugging, with little if any cost in terms of execution speed.

Comment: @2501 Will try to add some examples, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @user300234 I realize that is too broad now. I have updated the question but I'm not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: @2501 I have updated the question, but as you said it seems that is too broad and also opinion based, so I'm not really sure that if I can improve it further.

Comment: @Mahdi globals (and static locals, which will behave the same way) makes your function non-reentrant. It will add a lot of problems if you'll ever need to call this function from multiple threads at the same time. Making functions reentrant is usually a good thing.

Comment: @keltar Thanks for the input. Do you suggest only return values in the end of function calls -- even if they are about 100K long and it should be repeated for couple of thousands of files?

Comment: @Mahdi: try to choose one option. Come up with an example/solution-and request feedback on that maybe that is better idea.

Comment: @Mahdi depends on the task. If you **need** complete array of data - then in any case you'll have to store it somewhere. If you only need to e.g. iterate through each element - then there is no need to returning anything beside current element, while saving parsing state in provided context and then resuming parsing on next call.

Comment: @user300234 Thanks, I will ask more specifically in another question.

Comment: @keltar That makes sense. If you post it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the matter of question, global ans local static variables behaves the same way. They both counts as 'global' for the sake of specific functions, end thus cannot be used from many calls simultaneously (called from multiple concurrent threads).

To answer the question it is required to know the requirements and end goal for this code.

Some tasks require final set of data as result - which will grow with larger files, but still have to be complete before it could be used. As an example you could think of list of unique words in file (or set of files).

Other tasks permits iterative approach - you can call function many times, each time checking return value and processing it. Some specific return value says that there is no more data and you should stop calling it at this point. Example is file reading functions, like `fread` - you call it many times, and each time it continues reading from where it stopped last time. The same task *could* be done with forming full data set - like allocating as much memory as needed and reading whole file into it; it is quite different, less flexible approach. It however may be required for some higher level task, the one that processes data.

Some tasks permits both approaches, e.g. XML parsing may be DOM or SAX. But still, there is a higher-level goal that decides which approach to use (DOM may be easier to use, but SAX is prefered if data is acquired from slow source, e.g. internet, while there is a need to display at least parts of data while it isn't fully loaded yet).

Comment: I'm accepting this because it in fact merged two of my options in one: using `static` and _Global Variables_, plus being aware of the thread-safety and Reentrancy issues, are both nice and definitely will help me write better code. Thanks!